# NodeJS: async await problem inside waterfall

Tags: node.js, async-await, callback, sequelize.js

I am using async waterfall model to work step by step in nodejs.

I am facing problem while calling promise based funcation and I think await is not working properly.

```
    async (fields, nextCall) => {
        let newUserDetails = {};
        newUserDetails.phone_no = fields.phone_no

        let insertedCityData = await insertCityName(fields.city_id, fields.state_id)
        newUserDetails.city_id = insertedCityData.city_id

        if (fields.user_type == 2) {

        } else if (fields.user_type == 3) {

        } else if (fields.user_type == 4) {
            newUserDetails.full_name = fields.first_name + ' ' + fields.last_name
            UserDetailsSchema.create(newUserDetails).then((users_details) => {
                nextCall(null, fields)
            }).catch(err => {
                return nextCall(MSG.SWW + '-0');
            })
        }
    },
    (fields, nextCall) => {
     // I am getting error over here that user_type is undefined
     if (fields.user_type == 2) { 

     }


function insertCityName(cityName, stateId) {
    console.log('insertCityName')
    return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
        async.waterfall([
            (nextCall) => {
                // insert city name
                let newCityName = {}
                newCityName.city_name = cityName
                newCityName.state_id = stateId

                CitySchema.create(newCityName).then(data => {
                    const addedCity = data.get({ plain: true })
                    nextCall(null, addedCity)
                }).catch(err => {
                    console.log(err)
                    return nextCall(MSG.SWW);
                })
            },
        ], (err, response) => {
            if (err) {
                reject({
                    status: 0,
                    message: err || MSG.SWW
                })
            }
            resolve(response)
        })
    })
}
```

insertCityName promise function is may be not waiting and calling `nextCall` and due to that I am getting `fields` undefined.

How can I achieve this?

DD: in 1st step I am waiting for insertCityName function get executed then I am setting up it's returned city_id and based on `user_type` it goes to next conditions so here `user_type` is 4 so it will insert data in UserDetails and then from there I am calling `nextCall` cb so it has to goto next 2nd step and I should get `fields` variable with all the values. but this is not happing it is shows `undefined`.

ERROR: `TypeError: Cannot read property 'user_type' of undefined`

Comment: This is a very difficult way to write this. With the use of `await`, I don't understand why you're complicating things with `async.waterfall()` at all.  You can just sequence things using `await` in nice simple code.  Plus, there's no point to waterfall if you only pass it one function.  Get rid of the async library entirely from this code and life will be simpler.

Comment: @jfriend00 you are right but basically this code is old with ES5 and there are several things in this waterfall model so I can't do your way.

Comment: Well, you're already using `await` so this is now ES7 code.  You don't need waterfall at all.  It just makes things more complicated.  And, if you're not going to show us the rest of the waterfall code, we can't show you how to get rid of it.

Comment: @jfriend00 yes you are right but I can't get rid of the other code as it will impect more on the system

Comment: What exactly isn't waiting for what?  I can't tell what the actual core problem is that you want help for.  Please be more specific in describing the exact problem.

Comment: @jfriend00 In the 1st step I am waiting for the function response then there are conditions in which I have set `nextCall` to call the next step but may be it is not wating and I am getting `undefined` `user_type` in 2nd step as whole `fields` is undefined

Comment: Sorry, did not understand any of that last comment.

Comment: @jfriend00 I have added DD in question plz check

Comment: Did you ever resolved this issue? If yes, please provide solution when you find time. Thx

Comment: @Blejzer I did found the workaround. I used .then() method instead of await and it worked.